# How can I find a different user profile using the LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

What I want to do is use the LinkedIn API to access a arbitrary user profile, get the image (if there is a public one) and use that image. If a user is authenticated, I can get their image using:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json
```

But I cannot figure out what to replace the tilda (`~`) with to find an arbitrary user (i.e. using an email address). If I simply put in the email address, it won't find the user.

Is it possible to get info from an arbitrary user profile (assuming that it is public)?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible getting an arbitrary user informations by using LinkedIn API. The user must authenticate the application by his or her username and password.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I figured, but was hoping for a different response.

Answer (score 0):

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088088/linkedin-rest-api-user-profile) gives a working example how to access a profile by url. I suppose that adding `picture-url` will work.