# LinkedIn REST API - User Profile

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How to get user profile by LinkedIn member ID -not app scoped user ID- on LinkedIn REST API?

I'm able to fetch user profile following use cases;

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Ftugrultopuz?format=json
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=dfECeltzw2?format=json
```

But I can't following use case;

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=40554663?format=json
```